# Tricount balances change after each reimbursement

Tags: expenses, travel, reimbursement

My friends and I are using Tricount to keep track of shared expenses during our trips. It is an excellent app but it seems to have an absolutely infuriating problem: whenever someone makes a reimbursement and marks it as such in the Balances sheet, balances change *completely*.

For instance, let's say that at the end of the trip, I owe $50 to Alice: after I reimbursed her and marked the $50 as paid, the Balances sheet changes completely, and I now owe again $20 to Alice!

We've been plagued with this problem for some time now. It makes using Tricount for reimbursement a chore, and we basically cannot trust it anymore.

Are we missing something?

Comment: I don't know Tricount. But did you find out *why* it says you owe Alice $50? Presumably, you can do the same calculations on a calculator and see where Tricount gets it wrong.

Comment: à Beaune!  you know, could it be a plain bug in the app, unfortunately.  it's pretty common on relatively less-popular apps  :/

Comment: @Fattie As far as I can tell, Tricount is *extremely* popular...

Comment: gotchya, hopefully then someone has an answer to this actually practical question on the site !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the fact that (1) Tricount doesn't automatically pull new expenses, and (2) someone made a reimbursement based on out-of-date expenses.

I have reached out to the Tricount support to report this error-prone behavior: Tricount shouldn't let people do reimbursement based on out-of-date expenses.